# Can I make transitions within a CSS animation quicker?

Tags: html, css

So my goal is to have a pure CSS background image that just fades in and out of different images.. it works and is great, I'm just wondering if there is anyway to make the transitions quicker so I don't have to see both images eased together.. I know there are different ways of controlling how that transition happens using the timing function - I'm just wondering if there is any other way? I tried using different keyframe stop points to call the next image followed by the same image 2% later to in my mind, complete the transition quicker but it didn't seem to work.. any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/FE948/

```
<div></div>   

body {
background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/headerbg.jpg') !important;}
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
 25% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/headerbg.jpg');}
 48% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg2.jpg');}
 50% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg2.jpg');}
 73% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg3.jpg');}
 75% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg3.jpg');}
 97% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/headerbg.jpg');}
 99% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/headerbg.jpg');}
}

body {
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 27s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: slider;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the animation duration? It's the controlling factor...unless there is something else going on.

Comment: Yeah well that's the duration of it overall. Just wondering if it's possible to change the transition duration with a clever work around or something.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do then.

Comment: Insert an animation frame that still holds the _same_ background image immediately _before_ the frame that sets a new one, f.e. `47.999% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/headerbg.jpg');}` and so on for the rest of them.

Comment: Worth a read: http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions

Comment: I want the transition from one image to the other to be made quicker, that's all. I know it will be made quicker overall of I bring the overall duration down but then it makes the "slides" not stay as long.

Comment: @CBroe I'll try that out when I get back to my computer. Looks like a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following keyframe percentages.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slider {
    32% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/headerbg.jpg');}
    34% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg2.jpg');}
    65% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg2.jpg');}
    67% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg3.jpg');}
    98% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/headerbg3.jpg');}
    100% {background-image:url('http://patheoslabs.com/valuesandcapitalism/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/headerbg.jpg');}
```

}

These should allow for quicker transitions.